# Excel Oracle Query Group Function Not Allowed Here

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, odbc

I am making a Excel Oracle Query to achieve the following.

I have two tables, one table with orders and when the are invoiced and one table with exchange rates and from which date that rate is applicable:

Table JOBS:

```
ID   INVOICE_DATE
1    05-05-2017
2    05-03-2017
3    04-28-2017
4    04-15-2017
5    04-01-2017
6    03-28-2017
7    03-15-2017
8    03-02-2017
9    02-27-2017
```

Table EXCHG:

```
CURR   RATE   DATE_FROM
USD    0.92   05-01-2017
GBP    1.21   05-01-2017
USD    0.95   04-04-2017
GBP    1.18   04-04-2017
USD    0.94   04-01-2017
GBP    1.19   04-01-2017
USD    0.91   03-03-2017
GBP    1.17   03-03-2017
USD    0.92   03-01-2017
GBP    1.20   03-01-2017
USD    0.93   02-01-2017
GBP    1.21   02-01-2017
```

I want to get the orders with invoice dates and the applicable exchange rate at that moment.

Currently I have the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT JOBS.ID, JOBS.INVOICE_DATE, EXCHG.CURR, EXCHG.RATE, EXCHG.DATE_FROM

FROM LOC.JOBS JOBS

LEFT JOIN LOC.EXCHG EXCHG
ON (JOBS.INVOICE_DATE-EXCHG.DATE_FROM) >= 0) AND (JOBS.INVOICE_DATE-EXCHG.DATE_FROM <= 31)

WHERE
EXCHG.CURR = 'USD'
```

And this is working fine except that I get some orders double with two or more exchange rates:

```
ID   INVOICE_DATE   RATE_USD   DATE_FROM
1    5/5/2017       0.92       5/1/2017
1    5/5/2017       0.95       4/4/2017
2    5/3/2017       0.92       5/1/2017
2    5/3/2017       0.95       4/4/2017
3    4/28/2017      0.95       4/4/2017
3    4/28/2017      0.94       4/1/2017
4    4/15/2017      0.95       4/4/2017
4    4/15/2017      0.94       4/1/2017
5    4/1/2017       0.94       4/1/2017
5    4/1/2017       0.91       3/3/2017
5    4/1/2017       0.92       3/1/2017
6    3/28/2017      0.91       3/3/2017
6    3/28/2017      0.92       3/1/2017
7    3/15/2017      0.91       3/3/2017
7    3/15/2017      0.92       3/1/2017
8    3/2/2017       0.92       3/1/2017
8    3/2/2017       0.93       2/1/2017
9    2/27/2017      0.93       2/1/2017
```

What I would like to get is:

```
ID   INVOICE_DATE   RATE_USD   DATE_FROM
1    5/5/2017       0.92       5/1/2017
2    5/3/2017       0.92       5/1/2017
3    4/28/2017      0.95       4/4/2017
4    4/15/2017      0.95       4/4/2017
5    4/1/2017       0.94       4/1/2017
6    3/28/2017      0.91       3/3/2017
7    3/15/2017      0.91       3/3/2017
8    3/2/2017       0.92       3/1/2017
9    2/27/2017      0.93       2/1/2017
```

I am trying to figure out how to do this, somehow I need to select the minimum of the result of these two statements:

```
JOBS.INVOICE_DATE-EXCHG.DATE_FROM >= 0 AND JOBS.INVOICE_DATE-EXCHG.DATE_FROM <= 31
```

The best I can come up with is:

```
SELECT JOBS.ID, JOBS.INVOICE_DATE, EXCHG.CURR, EXCHG.RATE, EXCHG.DATE_FROM

FROM LOC.JOBS JOBS

LEFT JOIN LOC.EXCHG EXCHG
ON (MIN(JOBS.INVOICE_DATE-EXCHG.DATE_FROM) AND (JOBS.INVOICE_DATE-EXCHG.DATE_FROM >= 0))

WHERE
EXCHG.CURR = 'USD'
```

But this gives me the following error:
[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

Can someone please solve this issue for me? I would be really happy.

Floris

PS. This is my first question here so I hope it is good :)

Answer (score 0):

"Do the simplest thing that could possibly work" - Ward Cunningham

I suggest that you add another column to your EXCHG table named DATE_TO which represents the expiration date of the exchange rate. Whenever you get a new exchange rate for a particular currency you set DATE_TO on whatever row matches the currency and has DATE_TO = NULL, which can be done using a compound trigger. Then your query becomes:

```
SELECT j.ID,
       j.INVOICE_DATE,
       e.CURR,
       e.RATE,
       e.DATE_FROM
  FROM LOC.JOBS j
  LEFT OUTER JOIN LOC.EXCHG e
    ON (j.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN e.DATE_FROM
                           AND e.DATE_TO) OR
       (e.DATE_FROM <= j.INVOICE_DATE AND e.DATE_TO IS NULL)
  WHERE e.CURR = 'USD'
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you Bob, but I am afread adding a column to the EXCHG table is not possible. The table is not under my control and based on a very old system which is no longer updated. Do you have any other suggestions?